# A vector along a trapezoid's diagonal

Tags: vectors

> In the trapezoid TXYZ, $\vec{TX} = 2 \vec{ZY},$ and the diagonals meet at $O.$ Find an expression for the vector $\vec{TO}$ in terms of the vectors $\vec{TX}$ and $\vec{TZ}.$

I do not know how to answer this question. It involves the properties of vectors.

What I have done so far:

Let $\vec{TX}$ = unit vector $\mathbf{a},$ then $\vec{ZY}=\frac12$ unit vector $\mathbf{a}.$

Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a hint without reading the rest of the following answer, you could refer to [this different-looking example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3905482/21813), which utilises the same solution technique.
$$$$

---

We need to determine the position of point $O.$ Start by constructing a diagram, labelling it as helpfully as possible. As such, let
$$\vec{ZY}=\mathbf{a},\\
\vec{TZ}=\mathbf{b},\\
\vec{TO}=m\,\vec{TY},\\
\vec{ZO}=n\,\vec{ZX}.$$

Now we form an equation relating $m, n, \mathbf{a},$ and $\mathbf{b}:$

> $$\vec{TO}=\vec{TZ}+\vec{ZO}\\ m\,\vec{TY}=\mathbf{b}+n\,\vec{ZX}\\ m(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})=\mathbf{b}+n(2\mathbf{a}- \mathbf{b})\\ (m-2n)\mathbf{a}+(m+n-1)\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}.$$

Since $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are not collinear, the coefficients of both vectors are $0.$

> Therefore, $m=\frac23.$ So
>  $$\vec{TO}=\frac23\vec{TY}\\ =\frac23(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})\\ =\frac13(2\mathbf{a})+\frac23(\mathbf{b})\\ =\frac13\vec{TX}+\frac23\vec{TZ}.$$

---

Alternatively, to determine the position of point $O$ without relying just on vector properties, we can just use triangle similarity.

> Triangle $OTX$ is similar to triangle $OYZ.$ So
>  $$\frac{OT}{OY}=\frac{TX}{YZ}\\=2.$$
>  Thus $$TO=\frac23TY\\ \vec{TO}=\frac23\vec{TY}\\ =\frac23(\vec{TZ}+\vec{ZY})\\ =\frac23(\vec{TZ}+\frac12\vec{TX})\\ =\frac13\vec{TX}+\frac23\vec{TZ}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I got it now!